# Change column type from Varchar to numeric in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I change column type from varchar to numeric which has data already in it, and the data is numbers.

SQL SERVER

Comment: You could add a new numeric column. Copy/convert data. Drop old column. Rename new column. But watch out for dependencies! (fk's, triggers, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this,

- 1, Create a new numeric column
- 2, update new column with data from varchar column
- 3, check and confirm the data in numeric column
- 4, drop varchar column

But as mentioned in the comments you need to be aware of triggers.FKs etc
Updated to use [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table ADD numeric_column(x,y); --x, y here is the precision, scale
GO

UPDATE dbo.table
SET    numeric_column = TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(x,y),varchar_numbers_column)
GO

ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN varchar_numbers_column
GO
```

Using Try_Convert, returns NULL when conversion fails

```
SELECT
     Failed_Date        = TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(12,2), '12/31/2010')
    ,Failed_#           = TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(12,2), '#')
    ,WorkingWholeNumber = TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(12,2), '3')
    ,WorkingDecimal     = TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(12,2), '5.67')
```

Comment: I'm getting this error   "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Comment: are you sure the data in the varchar column are all numbers?

Comment: @Hamilton - update answer